# How to write testcase for showing dialog using mockito for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

```
 Future<void> showPopUp() async {
    return await showDialogPopup(
      context: _context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: CaregiverWelcomeDialog(
          CaregiverWelcomeModalViewModel(_localizer!),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> handleCaregiverRouteforWeb() async {
    await _userService.updateWebUserLoggedInStatus();

    final isCaregiver =
        _userService.currentUser?.userType == IrisUserType.Caregiver;

    if (isCaregiver) {
      await showPopUp();
    }

    _navigationService.goToRoute(HomeRoute);

    if (_featureFlagService.hasAccess(FeatureFlag.BrazeIAMEvent)) {
      _behaviorTrackerService
          .track(getUserProfileAppOnboardingCompleted(buildContext));
    }

    return;
  }
```

```
test(
      'handleCaregiverRoute should update web user status and show dialog if caregiver on web',
      () async {
    final mockBuildContext = MockBuildContext();
    final testLocalizer = TestLocalizer();

    final viewModel = DeviceVerificationScreenViewModel(
      testLocalizer,
      context: mockBuildContext,
      memberInformation: memberInformationMinusPhone,
    );

    when(mockUserService.currentUser).thenReturn(caregiverMock);

    // Mock navigation service
    when(mockNavigationService.goToRoute(HomeRoute))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => null);

    // Mock feature flag service
    when(mockFeatureFlagService.hasAccess(FeatureFlag.BrazeIAMEvent))
        .thenReturn(false);

    // Mock showDialogPopup with non-null context
    when(
      showDialogPopup(
        context: mockBuildContext,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: CaregiverWelcomeDialog(
            CaregiverWelcomeModalViewModel(testLocalizer),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ).thenAnswer((_) async {});

    // Act
    await viewModel.handleCaregiverRouteforWeb();

    // Verify that showDialogPopup is called with the correct context
    verify(
      showDialogPopup(
        context: mockBuildContext,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (_) => WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: CaregiverWelcomeDialog(
            CaregiverWelcomeModalViewModel(testLocalizer),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ).called(1);

    // Verify other expectations
    verify(mockNavigationService.goToRoute(HomeRoute)).called(1);
    expect(mockUserService.currentUser?.userType, IrisUserType.Caregiver);
    verify(mockBehaviorTrackerService.track(any));

    // Verify that showPopUp is NOT called
    verifyNever(viewModel.showPopUp());
  });
```

I wrote this testcase but getting 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' error for showPopUp . I checked if context and localizer are null but they are not null still getting this error. Help me cover the last 3 lines in the method including navigation also in the testcase. How to cover all the lines in the method and get rid of Null error. Please help.

```
test/view_models/device_verification_screen_view_model_test.dart 25:7                                            MockBuildContext.widget
package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart 296:17                                                                    debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<fn>
package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart 311:4                                                                     debugCheckHasMediaQuery
package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart 1025:12                                                             MediaQuery._of
package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart 1021:12                                                             MediaQuery.of
package:ui_library/responsive/orientation_util.dart 5:23                                                         OrientationUtil.getScreenWidth
package:ui_library/responsive/iris_responsive_style.dart 36:45                                                   IrisResponsiveStyle.deviceWidth
package:ui_library/responsive/iris_responsive_style.dart 49:12                                                   IrisResponsiveStyle.screenSize
package:ui_library/responsive/iris_device_type.dart 41:32                                                        new IrisDeviceType.from
package:ui_library/responsive/iris_responsive_style.dart 53:27                                                   IrisResponsiveStyle.deviceType
package:iris/core/domain/mixins/braze_event_mixin.dart 30:16                                                     BrazeEventsMixin.getUserProfileAppOnboardingCompleted
package:iris/features/account_create/presentation/view_models/device_verification_screen_view_model.dart 321:18  DeviceVerificationScreenViewModel.handleCaregiverRouteforWeb
```

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting when you run your test. 

Also, which line of your test is failing?

Comment: I have added the error

Comment: class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}
This line is test/view_models/device_verification_screen_view_model_test.dart 25:7                                            MockBuildContext.widget